# FOR ALL ENTRIES CONCEPT

Tags: abap

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF TY_FINAL,
        VBELN TYPE VBELN_VA,
        ERDAT TYPE ERDAT,
        AUART TYPE AUART,
*        KUNNR TYPE KUNAG,
         BEZEI TYPE BEZEI,

        POSNR TYPE POSNR_VA,
        MATNR TYPE MATNR,
        KWMENG TYPE KWMENG,
        NETPR TYPE NETPR,

        KUNNR TYPE KUNNR,
        NAME1 TYPE NAME1_GP,
        MAKTX TYPE MAKTX,
         END OF TY_FINAL.


  DATA : IT_FINAL TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF TY_FINAL,
         WA_FINAL TYPE TY_FINAL.

  PARAMETERS : P_KUNNR TYPE KUNNR.


  SELECT VBELN
         ERDAT
         AUART
         KUNNR FROM VBAK INTO TABLE IT_FINAL WHERE KUNNR = P_KUNNR.



    IF SY-SUBRC = 0.

      SELECT POSNR MATNR KWMENG NETPR FROM VBAP INTO TABLE IT_FINAL FOR ALL ENTRIES IN IT_FINAL WHERE VBELN = IT_FINAL-VBELN.



        SELECT KUNNR NAME1 FROM KNA1 INTO TABLE IT_FINAL FOR ALL ENTRIES IN IT_FINAL WHERE KUNNR = IT_FINAL-KUNNR.


        SELECT AUART BEZEI FROM TVAKT INTO TABLE IT_FINAL FOR ALL ENTRIES IN IT_FINAL WHERE AUART = IT_FINAL-AUART.


          SELECT MATNR MAKTX FROM MAKT INTO TABLE IT_FINAL  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN IT_FINAL WHERE MATNR = IT_FINAL-MATNR.


      ENDIF.


      LOOP AT IT_FINAL INTO WA_FINAL.

        MOVE-CORRESPONDING WA_FINAL TO   WA_FINAL.

        READ TABLE IT_FINAL INTO WA_FINAL WITH KEY KUNNR = WA_FINAL-KUNNR.



        IF SY-SUBRC = 0.

          WA_FINAL-NAME1 = WA_FINAL-NAME1.

          ENDIF.



        READ TABLE IT_FINAL INTO WA_FINAL WITH KEY AUART = WA_FINAL-AUART.


        IF SY-SUBRC = 0.

          WA_FINAL-BEZEI = WA_FINAL-BEZEI.

          ENDIF.


         READ TABLE IT_FINAL INTO WA_FINAL WITH KEY MATNR = WA_FINAL-MATNR.


         IF SY-SUBRC = 0.

         WA_FINAL-MAKTX = WA_FINAL-MAKTX.

         ENDIF.

      APPEND WA_FINAL TO IT_FINAL.

      CLEAR : WA_FINAL.

        ENDLOOP.


       cl_demo_output=>display( IT_FINAL ).
```

output not coming . anyone can help me plzz

Comment: What do you mean with "output not coming"? Do you get no output at all? Or do you get output, but not the output you are expecting?

Comment: By the way, you seem to follow certain development practices that are not very up-to-date. You might want to check from when your learning resource are and look for something more modern.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see how to ask questions, e.g. use a meaningful title, explain the context, provide a **minimal** reproducible example and information about debug, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines in your code:

```
MOVE-CORRESPONDING WA_FINAL TO   WA_FINAL.
WA_FINAL-NAME1 = WA_FINAL-NAME1.
WA_FINAL-BEZEI = WA_FINAL-BEZEI.
WA_FINAL-MAKTX = WA_FINAL-MAKTX.
```

do exactly nothing. You are copying a value to the same field it's already in.

It seems like your problem is that you are trying to read the data from 5 different `SELECT`s all into the same internal table `IT_FINAL`. And then you only have one work-area `WA_FINAL`. That's not going to work. If you want to read one row and then move some of it to another row, then you are going to need at least two work-areas.

What you should do is create a **separate** internal table for **each** of those database tables. And also have separate work area structures for reading each of those internal tables.

```
SELECT VBELN
      ERDAT
      AUART
      KUNNR 
FROM VBAK 
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_final
WHERE KUNNR = p_kunnr.

IF it_vbap IS NOT INITIAL.
   SELECT POSNR 
          MATNR 
          KWMENG 
          NETPR 
   FROM VBAP 
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS IF TABLE it_vbap
   FOR ALL ENTRIES IN IT_FINAL
   WHERE VBELN = it_final-vbeln.
ENDIF.

LOOP AT it_final INTO wa_final.
    READ TABLE it_vbap INTO wa_vbap WITH KEY KUNNR = WA_FINAL-KUNNR.
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
        MOVE-CORRESONDING wa_vbap TO wa_final. 
        MODIFY it_final FROM wa_final. 
    ENDIF.
    
ENDLOOP.
```

This is just one of the additional tables, but it should not be difficult for you to do the same thing with the others. Note that there are 4 different variables here:

- `it_final`, the table that starts with the data from `VBAK` that is then gains additional data from other tables.
- `wa_final`, the work-area for that table.
- `it_vbap`, the table with the data from `VBAP`
- `wa_vbap`, the work-area for the VBAP table.

---

Or alternatively, you could learn how to do `OUTER JOIN`s in a `SELECT` and do this whole program with a single SELECT. But the single thing I can read from the sparse title and description of your question is that you want to learn how to do this with `FOR ALL ENTRIES`, so that's what I wrote about.